# FirebaseMessagingService Class does not get recognized by my spring boot project

Tags: spring-boot, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am making a spring boot project with firebase integration for push notifications. To get registered tokens from the client side, I need to extends the class `FirebaseMessagingService`, which is not recognized by the import.

What i can do to resolve it? And can you also tell me how firebase push notifications works?

```
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;


public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService
{

}
```